# raise OverflowError("Overflow in int64 addition") OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to calculating total age through minadmit and date of birth columns.
I tried this :

```
patient_admission['minadmit'] = pd.to_datetime(patient_admission['minadmit'], infer_datetime_format=True)
patient_admission['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(patient_admission['DOB'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print("*******************")
print(patient_admission['minadmit'])
print("*******************")
print(patient_admission['DOB'])
```

And this is the result :

```
*******************
0       2149-12-17 20:41:00
1       2149-12-17 20:41:00
2       2149-12-17 20:41:00
3       2188-11-12 09:22:00
4       2110-07-27 06:46:00
                ...        
58971   2111-09-30 12:04:00
58972   2161-07-15 12:00:00
58973   2135-01-06 07:15:00
58974   2129-01-03 07:15:00
58975   2149-06-08 15:21:00
Name: minadmit, Length: 58976, dtype: datetime64[ns]
*******************
0       2075-03-13
1       2075-03-13
2       2075-03-13
3       2164-12-27
4       2090-03-15
           ...    
58971   2026-05-25
58972   2124-07-27
58973   2049-11-26
58974   2076-07-25
58975   2098-07-25
Name: DOB, Length: 58976, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

After that, I just write this :

```
patient_admission['age'] = list(map(lambda x: x.days , (patient_admission['minadmit'] - patient_admission['DOB'])/365.242 ))
```

I have this error :

> raise OverflowError("Overflow in int64 addition") OverflowError: Overflow in int64 addition

What is the cause of this error, and how can can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
patient_admission['date_of_admission'] = pd.to_datetime(patient_admission['date_of_admission']).dt.date
patient_admission['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(patient_admission['DOB']).dt.date
```

Along with it not sure if this will fix but you may need to use `x.dt.days` in your lambda function